# Is there any way to get Future Response without using isDone() method/better way?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-boot

Recently implemented @Async feature to make a call to different RESTful web services and handling response like below

```
while(!response.get(i).isDone()) {
}
if(response.get(i).get()){
// some logic 
}
```

and everything is working fine. but now if any Restful web service not respond for long time due to some reasons (like service not available, service was down...) so that time below code goes to infinite loop or until it respond it back.

```
      while(!response.get(i).isDone()) {
      }
```

So, Please help me to resolve above issue

Comment: Why would you use a spinlock while waiting for the task to finish?

Comment: @kayaman, then how do get to know task is finished or not?

Comment: Do you need to know whether the task is finished, or do you need the result of the task?

Comment: Just use the `get()` method. If you had bothered to read the documentation you'd see that it blocks until the task has finished. Jeez.

Comment: i want to  know whether the task is finished or not?.

Comment: No you don't. Your spinlock code isn't interested in knowing **whether** the task is finished, it's interested in knowing **when** it's finished, so it can get the return value. That's what `get()` does, except without spinning. Well documented in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()). Next time read the documentation before asking a question here.